# How do I turn off browser caching for my entire ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I'd like to disable browser caching for every page on my site. I know I can do it per action, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do it site-wide.

Comment: Are you in control of the web server?  If it's IIS, it would be easier to disable caching on the server (via the Cache-Control HTTP header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Byron - as per your nudge :)

```
add the pragma no-cache directive header into the master page!!
```

along the lines of:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

Cheers -have a good weekend

jim

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom base controller class, you can override it's `OnResultExecuting()` method and put the same code you would use per action there.

Comment: or add the pragma no-cache directive header into the master page??